# Does Rust have a type or trait that all entities "inherit" or implement?

Tags: rust

In Java, all objects inherit from `java.lang.Object`.  In Go, all types/structs implement the empty interface `interface {}`. Is there any similar construct in the Rust language?

If the answer is no, what makes it unnecessary?  Is it because all entities in Rust (except modules) can be parameterized by type?  Does that remove the need for a common "supertype" or common Trait shared by all Rust entities/structs/enums?

Comment: There are some primitive traits that are added automatically by the compiler. See http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/std/kinds/index.html But there are four of them, according to the properties of the type. There is nothing unique that applies to all objects like `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a trait. It is `std::any::Any`.

From [the docs](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/any/trait.Any.html):

> The Any trait is implemented by all 'static types, and can be used for dynamic typing

Comment: -0: `Any` is *not* a common base class or supertype or anything like that. It is indeed more similar to Go's `interface{}`. But it's not idiomatic—almost always generics or some other trait should be what you use.

Comment: Also, unlike `interface{}` or the other examples, `Any` is actually just a trait that is defined in libstd and implemented like `impl<T> Any for T`, i.e. not fundamental to the language or compiler at all. (Although it does use a single compiler intrinsic internally to get a unique ID for each type.)

Comment: Great information - thanks. For my secondary question, based on these comments then it does appear that parameterized types of pretty much all entities in Rust alleviate the need for any common supertype or supertrait.

Comment: @huon Actually, I would argue that `Any` does depend on compiler support for it's functionality. The `type_id()` method that `Any` provides ultimately pulls from [core::intrinsics::type_id](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/intrinsics/fn.type_id.html) that uses a compiler intrinsic interface.

Comment: @penguin359, indeed that is the compiler intrinsic referenced :) I think my point was the interaction with the type system isn't special, it's 'just' a blanket impl (even if the  code within that interface needs a little bit of magic).

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it, if not completely unnecessary, it is less necessary in Rust to have a base type.

Note that the introduction of parametric polymorphism (generics) has removed most of the use cases for `Object` also in java.
With `Object` you can implement a "generic" method that can work with any kind of java type. On the other hand, when you have an `Object` you can't do much with it... You have to cast it back to the actual subtype to use it.

For instance, the old non-generic version of java collections worked with `Object`s, This means you had to work like this (sample is straight from [this post on Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html)):

```java
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.add(new Integer(1));
Integer num = (Integer) list.get(0);
```

`add` takes an `Object` (so you can use the collection with any type). But `get` returns an `Object` too, so you have to cast it back to `Integer` based on the knowledge that you (the programmer) have on what you originally inserted in the LinkedList. There's very little type safety here.

The new generic version of the same container, since java 1.5, is:

```java
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list.add(new Integer(1));
Integer num = list.get(0);
```

Now you have a list of `Integer`, so `add` takes `Integer` and `get` returns `Integer`. `Object` is nowhere to be seen any more (although due to type erasure it's just there, barely hiding under the hood...)

Note that Go's main use of `interface{}` stems from the fact that Go does not have generics. The main pattern of use for `interface{}` is roughly the same. You use it when you have to work with multiple types and you sort-of cast it ([although in a safer way](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and with [a more elegant pattern](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch)) back to a more useful type before using it.

With that in mind, you could theoretically use `Any` in Rust in the same way (checking actual type and casting to it before using it). It's just that you will likely not find many cases where this might be useful.
The code below works on rustc 0.13-nightly (2015-01-01), although I'm sure there are better ways to write it...

```
use std::any::{Any, AnyRefExt};

// just a couple of random types
struct Foo {
    a: f64
}

enum Bar {
    Baz(int),
    Qux
}

fn main() {
    // create an array of things that could have any type
    let anything = &[&1i as &Any, &Foo{a: 2.} as &Any, &Bar::Qux as &Any];

    // iterate and print only the integer
    for &any in anything.iter() {
        if any.is::<int>() { // check if type is int
            match any.downcast_ref::<int>() { // cast to int
                Some(a) => { println!("{}", *a); }
                None => panic!()
            }
            // or just (shorter version of the match)
            println!("{}", *any.downcast_ref::<int>().unwrap());
        }
    }
}
```